# Getting current page of a FlowDocumentPageViewer

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocumentPageViewer control that I am populating from the code behind.  I am adding text from 3-4 items.  I need to know on what page item 1,2,3... ends.

These items get added to a FlowDocument in a loop and then at the end I have

```
flowDocumentPageViewer.Document = resultsDocument;
```

However, even then if I call

```
flowDocumentPageViewer.PageCount
```

I still get 0.  If I do some event like a click and print the above PageCount after the window renders, it does print the correct value.  However, I need a running total of this value as I populate the FlowDocument.  I am hoping someone knows some kind of trick with text metrics or any other way that this could be solved.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this problem? Seeing as I have the same requirement and am also stuck with this :)

Answer (score 1):

You have no choice but to trigger a (virtual) render of your control to get this kind of info.

the easiest way is to force a `updateLayout()` on the FlowDocumentPageViewer, but this means it'll show the result before you get the info which is probably not what you want.

you can also use the `Arrange()` method if you don't want the content to be shown:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx

after using this on your control you should get the updated info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to be honest I still do. Any updateLayout() did not help. Now I use a timer to get the pagecount a second later after I assigend to document to the viewer. Works fine.